# setup.py module getting error when executing the code

Tags: python, csv

When i am executing this code
`

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from pathlib import Path


this_directory = Path(__file__).parent
long_description = (this_directory / "C:/Users/DELL/Downloads/cashflower-main/README.md").read_text()

setup(
    author="Zuzanna Chmielewska",
    description="Framework for actuarial cash flow models",
    include_package_data=True,
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    name="tutorials",
    packages=find_packages(include=["tutorials", "tutorials.*"]),
)
```

i am getting the error ......
Exception has occurred: SystemExit
usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
or: setup.py --help-commands
or: setup.py cmd --help

```
error: no commands supplied
distutils.errors.DistutilsArgError: no commands supplied

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  File "C:\Users\DELL\Downloads\cashflower-main\tutorials\setup.py", line 8, in <module>
    setup(
SystemExit: usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands
   or: setup.py cmd --help

error: no commands supplied
```

how can i resolve the error in setup.py

Answer (score 0):

The `setup.py` script is used to build a Python package from the source files.

You may beed the `wheel` package for building:

```
pip install wheel
```

You can build the package from the source files using the following commands:

```
python setup.py sdist
python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

for either source or wheel distributions respectively.

---

However, you don't need to build the package yourself. The package is already available on PyPI.

You can install it with the following command in the terminal:

```
pip install cashflower
```

After that you start using the package. Here's [the documentation](https://cashflower.acturtle.com/) to start off.